# Modals - Angular4

Tags: javascript, angular, modal-dialog

I'm looking for the best approach to implement modals in Angular 4 following the component architecture.

I've seen a lot of tutorials, external libraries, etc, and the usage it's quite limited. Basically all of them follow the approach of creating a Modal Service, to manage the modals and a modal component with transclude to change the template depending of the content. This requires that we need to put the modal in the template of the current component. Something like this:

```
@Component({
selector: 'modal',
template: `
    <div [ngClass]="{'closed': !isOpen}">
        <div class="modal-overlay" (click)="close(true)"></div>

        <div class="modal">
            <div class="title" *ngIf="modalTitle">
                <span class="title-text">{{ modalTitle }}</span>
                <span class="right-align" (click)="close(true)"><i class="material-icons md-24">clear</i></span>
            </div>

            <div class="body">
                <ng-content></ng-content>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And then the usage like this:

```
<modal title='My title'>
  <div>
    My Modal
  </div>
</modal>`
```

This a fine approach for small applications. For big applications this is not a great solution. The idea would be to have a service that open components dynamic without defining them. Something like this in the component:`this.openModal(CustomModal)`

The ng-bootstrap does something very similar to this, but it's using Bootstrap 4 and it is still in alpha, so currently we are not sure that it's a valid option. Any library that works in this way or any direction of how to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend not using ngx-bootstrap, and use [@ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io). ngx-bootstrap's lack of features, @ng-bootstrap has more features and stability.

I started with ngx-bootstrap and finally changed it. I also saw Angular team recommends @ng-bootstrap package in the ng-conf.

Actually, I contributed with some component of ngx-bootstrap cause are uncompleted.

Comment: ng-bootstrap doesn't require Bootstrap 4? And can you change the  base template of the modal?

Comment: You can use @ng-bootstrap with Bootstrap 3 o 4, both are supported. You can open a modal using ng-template like ngx-bootstrap, and open a Component (That's my favourite option) `this.modalService.open(MyComponent)`here more info: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal

Comment: Yes, ng-bootstrap its probably the most interesting and does what I'm expecting. Opening the modals by service passing the component. From your experience with the library, the Inputs and Outputs works ok with this? One of the ideas is to pass a object item to the modal, manipulating it using a form and then refreshing the main page after the request. So basically the  modal needs to send a response to the component that opens the modal. If that makes sense.